# Sharepoint. External Content Types. Passing values to stored procedure

Tags: sharepoint, stored-procedures, sharepoint-2010, bdc

I have simple stored procedure, that takes **couple** parameters and **updates** table.

How to pass parameters via BDC?

For example, to execute stored procedure, that selects rows and takes one param, code below.

```
        BdcService bdcservice = SPFarm.Local.Services.GetValue<BdcService>();
        IMetadataCatalog catalog = bdcservice.GetDatabaseBackedMetadataCatalog(SPServiceContext.Current);
        //  entity.GetLobSystem().GetLobSystemInstances()[0].Value;
        IEntity entity = catalog.GetEntity(Utils.EntityNamespace, "GetMessage");
        ILobSystemInstance lobSystemInstance = entity.GetLobSystem().GetLobSystemInstances()[0].Value;

        IFilterCollection filters = entity.GetDefaultFinderFilters();
        ComparisonFilter filter = (ComparisonFilter)filters[0];
        filter.Value = code;
        IEntityInstanceEnumerator enumerator = entity.FindFiltered(filters, lobSystemInstance);
        DataTable result = entity.Catalog.Helper.CreateDataTable(enumerator);
```

DataTable result contains selected rows.

But how to pass couple parameters to Update procedure?

```
 BdcService bdcservice = SPFarm.Local.Services.GetValue<BdcService>();
        IMetadataCatalog catalog = bdcservice.GetDatabaseBackedMetadataCatalog(SPServiceContext.Current);
        //  entity.GetLobSystem().GetLobSystemInstances()[0].Value;
        IEntity entity = catalog.GetEntity(Utils.EntityNamespace, "ContractAdd");
        ILobSystemInstance lobSystemInstance = entity.GetLobSystem().GetLobSystemInstances()[0].Value;


       // entity.ExecuteScalar();
```

entity has method "ExecuteScalar", but how to pass params via this method?